# Cassandra update column should update column value but not the ttl?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, ttl

I want to know if there is a way to update the column **value** in cassandra but the column **ttl** that is present already should remain the same.

Could you please let me know if this is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update the ttl to desired value while updating the column. I mean you can achieve it programatically. Please go through this page ( https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql-oss/3.3/cql/cql_using/useExpireExample.html ) for examples.

Comment: I had to get the ttl of current column and then update the column with value and the ttl.

Comment: I mean exactly same thing.